# What does this line of code mean in Julia Programming Language

Tags: arrays, string, syntax, julia

```
function commence(args::Vector{String})
```

What I would like to know is, what does this line mean? Particularly, what does the argument of commence, "`(args::Vector{String})`" mean?

Answer (score 4):

The line indicates the definition of a function named `commence` which takes a single argument `args`. The `::Vector{String}` bit specifies that only vectors of strings, i.e. objects of type `Vector{String}`, will be accepted by the function. See the following demonstration:

```
julia> function commence(args::Vector{String})
           @show args
           nothing
       end
commence (generic function with 1 method)

julia> commence([1,2,3])
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching commence(::Array{Int64,1})
Closest candidates are:
  commence(::Array{String,1}) at REPL[1]:2
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[2]:1

julia> commence("asd","test")
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching commence(::String, ::String)
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[3]:1

julia> commence(["asd","test"]) # works, since typeof(args) == Vector{String}
args = ["asd", "test"]
```

I recommend you read through the manual, in particular [this part](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/functions/), to learn more about functions in Julia.

Answer (score 0):

:: means enforce the type similar to typeassert().
Also see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/punctuation/ [Julia Puntuation][1]